# Want to change text when mouse is on it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have plain text, not a link, that I want to change when the mouse hovers over it, then revert back to the original text when the mouse moves away. I am unfamiliar with `JQuery`, so `JavaScript` would be best.

So, the text originally says **"Find the right dot"**, then when the mouse is over it, it changes to **"You found it!"**, then reverts to **"Find the right dot"** when the mouse moves away.

Comment: This can actually be done in CSS3 without javascript, it depends on your need, requires a modern browser.

Comment: You should really share with us what you've tried, error messages you've encountered, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try it with only css like this:

**Html:**

```
<div class="text">
    <p class="default">Find the right dot</p>
    <p class="found">You found it!</p>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
.text:hover p.found{display:block;}
.text:hover p.default{display:none;}
p.found{display:none;}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7dGMW/)**

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I have been searching online for a few days and had found nothing that worked. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the text in div tag(have some id)
2. getElementById that div
3. onMouseOver change innerHtml